# JAXB Parsing of similar xml files

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2, jaxb2-basics

I have different XML returns that I want to parse with JAXB with annotated classes.  Many of the XML files share a similar top structure and with the contents of an inner tag that can vary.  Since we sent the ContextInstance a class and not an instance I can't add classes.

How would you create a set of JAXB annotations that don't repeat the top level xml each time, given examples of two files like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2008-11-24 20:14:29</currentTime>
  <result>
    <serverOpen>True</serverOpen>
    <onlinePlayers>38102</onlinePlayers>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2008-11-24 20:17:29</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

And another file like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2012-02-12 14:39:12</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="characters" key="characterID"     columns="name,characterID,corporationName,corporationID">
      <row name="Alexis Prey" characterID="1365215823" corporationName="Puppies To the     Rescue" corporationID="238510404"/>
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2012-02-12 15:27:00</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

A common top level class would be something like

```
@XmlRootElement(name="eveapi")
public class EveApiConfig {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Date currentTime;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String cachedUntil;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "version", required = true)
    protected int version;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected ResultsConfig result;
}
```

But ResultsConfig would be number of other things.  it's almost like a need a reverse XmlSeeAlso

Any thoughts if how to do this?

Comment: Just adding more here.  My original question was about a desire to keep a single JAXB annotated class with subclasses for each specific implementation.

Comment: It doesnt' feel very DRY but for right now I'm implementing this by keeping a EveApiConfig superclass and creating subclasses for each specific implementation.  Still hoping there's a more elegant way to do this lost in my JAXB noobness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with several object factories. I'll sketch out the solution:

- Make `result` an `@XmlElementRef`, typed with something like `JAXBElement<AbstractResultConfig>`
- Per case create one package with an `ObjectFactory`
- In which of the `ObjectFactory` classes implement a different `@XmlElementDecl` factory method which would create `JAXBElement`s with instance of different subclasses of the `AbstractResultConfig`. Something like:

  ```
  @XmlElementDecl(name = "Result")
  public JAXBElement<ResultConfigImpl> createResultConfigImpl(ResultConfigImpl value) {
      return new JAXBElement<ResultConfigImpl>(..., ResultConfigImpl.class, null, value);
  }
  ```

I guess you'll need to pair ith with `createResultConfig()` method or something like this.